# Impact of rotation of the Earth on time travel

Tags: air-travel

During the flight of Dallas - Sydney, will the rotation of Earth have its effect, as the flight is going in the same direction as Earth Rotation.

As compared to Sydney - Dallas flight which is going in the opposite direction of the Earth rotation.

Comment: Do you mean "travel time" (i.e. how long it takes to travel) instead of "time travel" (science fiction topic)?

Comment: This has already [been addressed by physics.stackexchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16390/does-the-rotation-of-the-earth-dramatically-affect-airplane-flight-time) in detail.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly you mean by "time".

1. Time spent in the air: that is indeed a function of direction, primarily because of the prevailing winds. For example BOS->SFO is about half an hour longer than SFO->BOS. The prevailing winds are indeed partially caused by the earth's rotation.
2. Difference in local time: You gain or lose time by crossing time zones. In the example above, you gain three hours from BOS to SFO and you lose them again on the way back. BOS-SFO takes 6 hours in the air but it's only 3 hours in local time difference. Flying from Shanghai to San Francisco you arrive actually 3 hours before your departure. A 12-hour flight and 15-hour time zone difference.
3. Relativistic time shifts due to speed differences: that theoretically exists but is way way way too small for any meaningful impact. See link in the comments.

Comment: The relativistic time dilation effects of commercial air travel are measurable and have been measured directly. See the [Hafele-Keating experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hafele%E2%80%93Keating_experiment).

Comment: I think the original poster's question ponders the fact that the Earth is either rotating along with you or against you, slightly shortening or lengthening your trip as you fly east or west, but the effect will be very subtle indeed, especially considering prevailing winds are much more of a factor.